# freeing up memory for a linked list structure containing STL classes

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a linked list defined by a structure

```
struct node {
    std::string elem;
    std::vector<node *> children;
};
```

Supposing that it was properly dynamically allocated, how do you free the heap afterwards?
I am trying this:

```
void removeNodes(node* hElem) {
   for (node *hElemChildren: hElem->children)
       removeNodes(hElemChildren);
   delete hElem;
}
```

But I'm afraid that in this process I lose memory that was dynamically allocated to `std::string` and `std::vector`. Can someone please let me know if there is a memory leak here? Thanks!

Comment: You are not loosing memory with `string`, it is properly free with `delete hElem`

Comment: ...warning: you're opening yourself up for a rude dose of reality if `node`s with kids are ever copied. Just fyi. So long as you manage that well, you'll be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no memory-leak here. When you call delete, destructor of this element will be called, that will call destructor for `std::string` and then for `std::vector`.